# What is happening with getchar?

Tags: c, getchar

I am just looking for an explanation here.  I have a simple program loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("ready to begin? Enter y or n: ");
        char begin = getchar();
        if(begin == 'y')
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(begin == 'n')
        {
            printf("good-bye.");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("hu-ray\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this, much of the behavior is expected. Example: 'y' as input.

```
Ready to begin? Enter y or n: y
hu-ray
```

'n' as input also gives expected behavior along with just hitting ENTER.

```
Ready to begin? Enter y or n: n
good-bye.
Ready to begin? Enter y or n: 
Ready to begin? Enter y or n:
```

However, if I enter anything else, 'k' for example, I get this:

```
Ready to begin? Enter y or n: k
Ready to begin? Enter y or n: Ready to begin? Enter y or n:
```

more bizarre, the output of entering '12345':

```
Ready to begin? Enter y or n: 12345
Ready to begin? Enter y or n: Ready to begin? Enter y or n: Ready to begin? Enter y or n: Ready to begin? Enter y or n: Ready to begin? Enter y or n: Ready to begin? Enter y or n
```

Even after looking over the man page for `getchar()` I just do not understand what is happening here.  Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: The program does not see every key at the time it is struck... the keys are kept in a buffer and sent all together to your program after the `<newline>` (including it). Your program ignores everything except `y` and `n` (like `k` or `<ENTER>`) so it repeats the `while` loop.

Comment: cogito, Output looks correct.  What is bizarre about it?   What did you expect different?

Comment: when you press a character other then `y` and `n` , you are not handling that case and also there are `\n`s left over so `getchar` reads them,

Comment: As a side note, this is C++ (not C like the tag says) since `begin` is not defined at the start of the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every call to `getchar()` returns one character. So when you type a line at that prompt the next few characters are already provided to the next calls to `getchar()`.

You probably want to call `fgets()`.

Comment: huh, ok. I can see that, makes sense.  what about the 'k' example?  I see from @pmg that i am not handling any other chars except y and n, but why does the output look like it loops twice for k as an input? new line?

Comment: getchar() returns an int by the way, not a char.